# Is there a way to treat a word as a character in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, uikit, textkit

I'm looking to treat a word as a character in a `UITextView`.

I've previously got this working by detecting when a user has tried to delete a word, or if they've tried typing while in a word that we treat as a single character by seeing if the carat or selection is already within that word (using `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` and its cohorts) but was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

It looks like you can create your own tokenizer which allows you to redefine what a `UITextView` considers a character. Is it possible to make your own `UITextInputTokenizer` (or subclass UITextInputStringTokenizer) in order to do this? I've tried creating my own subclass of `UITextInputStringTokenizer` and overriding the 'tokenizer' method on the `UITextView` but it ends up not allowing *any* input whatsoever.

Any other more elegant solutions?